# Search image for color. Return X, Y

Tags: python, image, colors, find, python-imaging-library

I've been looking all over for a way to find a specific color in a image (screen capture), and return the the position of of the color (x,y). I've had some tries, but not managed to do a proper search. The result should be the first pixel found with that color.

I tought maybe PIL will be to any help. So I tried something like this, problem now is that it returns EVERY position, found with that color:

**Fixed:**

```
def FindColor(r,g,b):
    image = ImageGrab.grab()
    for x in range(1, 400):
        for y in range(1,400):
            px = image.getpixel((x, y))
            if px[0] == r and px[1] == g and px[2] == b:
                return(x,y)
```

And, I need to replace the loops range, with the pictures width/height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return` the result at the first match, instead of continuing the loop.

Comment: Sure, i forgot that i could do it that simple, as using the return-statement. 
Ty!